# basic question about machine learning and probabilistic framework?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

Why do we assume that the pair (X,Y) where X and Y are features and labels respectively are random variables governed by a probability distribution? Why does this assumption make sense? What if the underling source is deterministic?

Comment: We don't _always_ make that assumption (although we often do). You might get some mileage out of reading about the difference between a sample and a population

Answer (score 0):

x is considered a random variable if it is an outcome of a statistical experiment. Therefore the probability distribution is used to measure the value of x and it's possibility of its occurrence (i.e probability) when running a new experiment[1](http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/probability-distribution.aspx). 
If your underlying model is deterministic where no randomness existed then the system is considered deterministic [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system).